# what does exactly do cascade={"remove"} in a many to many relationship

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, cascade

I would like **tags** to be deleted when and only when an **article** is deleted AND thoses tags are not linked to any other article.
I tried cascade={'remove'} but it delete all tags link to the article I want to delete, even if thoses tags are ALSO linked to an other article.

**QUESTION**
- Is there a way to do that automatically thanks to annotation.
- If yes how?
- Otherwise should I do it manually in the controller? seems strange to have to it manually, means that I will have to make a loop for each tag and retrieve in the table article_tag to know if the tag is implemented more than once, if not then do $em->remove($tag).

**ENTITY SRUCTURE**
article (n)<---->(n) tags

**CODE**

```
 // IN ARTICLE ENTITY
 /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist","remove"})  **/
 private $tags;

 // IN TAG ENTITY 
 /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sdz\BlogBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="tags") **/
 private $articles;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `orphanRemoval`

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="contact", orphanRemoval=true) */
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal